# Remove array items by indexes

Tags: javascript, arrays

I would like to remove multiple items from an array by an array of indexes.

```js
const indexes = [0, 1, 3];
const values = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

indexes.forEach((idx) => {
  values.splice(idx, 1);
});

console.log(values);
```

When looping for the second time, the index is wrong because the array is shorter.

What should I do so the outcome would be `[2, 4, 5]`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're removing items from the array while iterating over it, which is a problem because after the first element gets removed, all the elements that follow it are no longer at the same index that the `indexes` are pointing to. Filter the array instead:

```js
const indexes = [0, 1, 3];
const values = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

const filtered = values.filter((_, i) => !indexes.includes(i));
console.log(filtered);
```

If you *must* mutate the existing array, go backwards so that the highest indexes get removed first:

```js
const indexes = [0, 1, 3];
const values = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

for (const index of indexes.sort((a, b) => b - a)) {
  values.splice(index, 1);
}

console.log(values);
```